# jQuery calculator second select is resetting all the time

Tags: javascript, jquery

everyone, I made this product calculator using jQuery and although it works, the second select is giving me a headache because I cannot get it to stay selected when you click an option even though it does what it's supposed to do. I know the reason this happens but the solution eludes me. I tried setting the option manually with the commented code in the calculator events block but that just freezes the second select and it doesn't really work for me that way.
I commented everything that seemed important so it is easier to read. my main problem is in the first part of the javascript I think.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

 // Set initial weights for first row
  var typeVal = $('#calcT1').val();
  var weights = weightOptions[typeVal];
  setWeights(weights, '#calcW1');

  // Letter Type change event
  $('.letterType').on('change', function () {
    var typeId = '#' + $(this).attr('id');
    var typeVal = $(typeId).val();
    var weightId = '#' + $(this).parents('.calculator-row').find('.letterWeight').attr('id');
    //console.log (weight);
    var weights = weightOptions[typeVal];

    setWeights(weights, weightId);

  });

  // Basically the calculator events
  $('.calculator-row').on('change keyup', function() {
    //var rowId = '#' + $(this).attr('id');
   // var typeId = '#' + $(this).find('.letterType').attr('id');
    //var typeVal = $(typeId).val();
    var weightId = '#' + $(this).find('.letterWeight').attr('id');
    var weightPrice = $(weightId + ' option:selected').attr('data-price');
    var weightValue = $(weightId).val();
    var inputId = '#' + $(this).find('.letterNumber').attr('id');
    var inputVal = $(inputId).val();
    var resultId = '#' + $(this).find('.letterSubtotal').attr('id');


    /*   $(weightId).val(weightValue);
     $(typeId).change(function () {
     });*/

    calculateRow(weightPrice, inputVal, resultId);
    calculateAll('.letterSubtotal', '#calcTotal');
  });

  // Set weight for target row using JSON Array
  function setWeights(json ,target) {
      $(target).empty();
      // Loop through the JSON object where i = index, and set data- attributes to <option> tags
      for (var i in json) {
        $(target).append($('<option>', {
          value: json[i]['wid'],
          text: json[i]['name'],
          'data-wmin': json[i]['wmin'],
          'data-wmax': json[i]['wmax'],
          'data-price': json[i]['price']
        }));
      }

  }

  /*


   // Set weights for the initial row
   /!*  setWeights(optionId, weightOptions);*!/

   // Set weights for sequential rows
   /!*  typeSelect.change(function () {
   optionId = $(this).val();
   setWeights(optionId, weightOptions);
   });*!/
   */
  // Add a new row
  var regex = /^(.+?)(\d+)$/i;
  var cloneIndex = $(".calculator-row").length;
  function addRow() {
    cloneIndex++;
    $(this).parents(".calculator-row").clone(true)
        .appendTo("#calculator")
        .attr("id", "calcRow" +  cloneIndex)
        .find("*")
        .each(function() {
          var id = this.id || "";
          var match = id.match(regex) || [];
          if (match.length == 3) {
            this.id = match[1] + (cloneIndex);
          }
          if ($(this).hasClass('calcDelRow')) {
            $(this).removeClass('hidden');
          }
          if ($(this).hasClass('letterNumber')) {
            $(this).val('');
          }
          if ($(this).hasClass('letterSubtotal')) {
            $(this).text('0.00');
          }
          /*if ($(this).hasClass('calcAddRow')) {
            $(this).addClass('hidden');
          }*/
        });

    calculateAll('.letterSubtotal', '#calcTotal');

  }

  // Remove row
  function removeRow(){
    $(this).parents(".calculator-row").remove();
    calculateAll('.letterSubtotal', '#calcTotal');
  }
  $("button").blur();
  $("button.calcAddRow").on("click", addRow);
  // Add remove event to button
  $("button.calcDelRow").on("click", removeRow);

  // Calculate a single row
  function calculateRow(a, b, target) {
    var x;
    x = parseFloat(a) * parseFloat(b);
    x = x.toFixed(2);

    if (!isNaN(x)) {
      $(target).text(x);
    } else {
      $(target).text('0.00');
    }
  }

  // Calculate total rows
  function calculateAll(rows, target) {
    var result = 0;
    $(rows).each(function () {
      if(!isNaN($(this).text())) {
        result += parseFloat($(this).text());
      } else {
        result = 0;
      }
    });
    $(target).text(result.toFixed(2));
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="calculator">
      <div class="calculator-row" id="calcRow1">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="form-group">
            <select id="calcT1" class="form-control letterType">
              <option value="1">Ordinaria piccolo</option>
              <option value="2">Ordinaria medio</option>
              <option value="3">Ordinaria extra</option>
              <option value="4">Raccomandata con avviso di ricevimento piccolo</option>
              <option value="5">Raccomandata con avviso di ricevimento medio</option>
              <option value="6">Raccomandata con avviso di ricevimento extra</option>
              <option value="7">Raccomandata semplice</option>
              <option value="8">Raccomandata con avviso di ricevimento</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <select id="calcW1" class="form-control letterWeight"></select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="number" id="calcNum1" class="form-control letterNumber" placeholder="No." min="0" max="999">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <h4><span>&euro;
</span><span id="calcSubtotal1" class="letterSubtotal">0.00</span></h4> 
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 center">
          <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default calcAddRow">Add
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default calcDelRow hidden">Remove
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-9">
      <h3><span>Totale: &euro;
</span><span id="calcTotal">0.00</span></h3> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  //Hardcoded Json 
  var weightOptions = {
    "1": {
      "1": {
        "price": "0.95",
        "wmin": "0",
        "wmax": "20",
        "name": "fino a 20 g"
      },
      "2": {
        "price": "2.55",
        "wmin": "21",
        "wmax": "50",
        "name": "Oltre 20 g e fino a 50 g "
      }
    },
    "2": {
      "1": {
        "price": "2.55",
        "wmin": "0",
        "wmax": "20",
        "name": "fino a 20 g"
      },
      "2": {
        "price": "2.55",
        "wmin": "21",
        "wmax": "50",
        "name": "Oltre 20 g e fino a 50 g "
      },
      "3": {
        "price": "2.85",
        "wmin": "51",
        "wmax": "100",
        "name": "Oltre 50 g e fino a 100 g"
      },
      "4": {
        "price": "3.50",
        "wmin": "101",
        "wmax": "250",
        "name": "Oltre 100 g e fino a 250 g"
      },
      "5": {
        "price": "4.35",
        "wmin": "251",
        "wmax": "350",
        "name": "Oltre 250 g e fino a 350 g"
      },
      "6": {
        "price": "5.40",
        "wmin": "351",
        "wmax": "1000",
        "name": "Oltre 350 g e fino a 1000 g"
      },
      "7": {
        "price": "5.95",
        "wmin": "1001",
        "wmax": "2000",
        "name": "Oltre 1000 g e fino a 2000 g"
      }
    },
    "3": {
      "1": {
        "price": "2.55",
        "wmin": "0",
        "wmax": "20",
        "name": "fino a 20 g"
      },
      "2": {
        "price": "2.85",
        "wmin": "21",
        "wmax": "50",
        "name": "Oltre 20 g e fino a 50 g "
      },
      "3": {
        "price": "3.50",
        "wmin": "51",
        "wmax": "100",
        "name": "Oltre 50 g e fino a 100 g"
      },
      "4": {
        "price": "4.35",
        "wmin": "101",
        "wmax": "250",
        "name": "Oltre 100 g e fino a 250 g"
      },
      "5": {
        "price": "5.95",
        "wmin": "251",
        "wmax": "350",
        "name": "Oltre 250 g e fino a 350 g"
      },
      "6": {
        "price": "5.95",
        "wmin": "351",
        "wmax": "1000",
        "name": "Oltre 350 g e fino a 1000 g"
      },
      "7": {
        "price": "6.50",
        "wmin": "1001",
        "wmax": "2000",
        "name": "Oltre 1000 g e fino a 2000 g"
      }
    },
    "4": {
      "1": {
        "price": "0.95",
        "wmin": "0",
        "wmax": "20",
        "name": "fino a 20 g"
      },
      "2": {
        "price": "2.55",
        "wmin": "21",
        "wmax": "50",
        "name": "Oltre 20 g e fino a 50 g "
      }
    },
    "5": {
      "1": {
        "price": "2.55",
        "wmin": "0",
        "wmax": "20",
        "name": "fino a 20 g"
      },
      "2": {
        "price": "2.55",
        "wmin": "21",
        "wmax": "50",
        "name": "Oltre 20 g e fino a 50 g "
      },
      "3": {
        "price": "2.85",
        "wmin": "51",
        "wmax": "100",
        "name": "Oltre 50 g e fino a 100 g"
      },
      "4": {
        "price": "3.50",
        "wmin": "101",
        "wmax": "250",
        "name": "Oltre 100 g e fino a 250 g"
      },
      "5": {
        "price": "4.35",
        "wmin": "251",
        "wmax": "350",
        "name": "Oltre 250 g e fino a 350 g"
      },
      "6": {
        "price": "5.40",
        "wmin": "351",
        "wmax": "1000",
        "name": "Oltre 350 g e fino a 1000 g"
      },
      "7": {
        "price": "5.95",
        "wmin": "1001",
        "wmax": "2000",
        "name": "Oltre 1000 g e fino a 2000 g"
      }
    },
    "6": {
      "1": {
        "price": "2.55",
        "wmin": "0",
        "wmax": "20",
        "name": "fino a 20 g"
      },
      "2": {
        "price": "2.85",
        "wmin": "21",
        "wmax": "50",
        "name": "Oltre 20 g e fino a 50 g "
      },
      "3": {
        "price": "3.50",
        "wmin": "51",
        "wmax": "100",
        "name": "Oltre 50 g e fino a 100 g"
      },
      "4": {
        "price": "4.35",
        "wmin": "101",
        "wmax": "250",
        "name": "Oltre 100 g e fino a 250 g"
      },
      "5": {
        "price": "5.95",
        "wmin": "251",
        "wmax": "350",
        "name": "Oltre 250 g e fino a 350 g"
      },
      "6": {
        "price": "5.95",
        "wmin": "351",
        "wmax": "1000",
        "name": "Oltre 350 g e fino a 1000 g"
      },
      "7": {
        "price": "6.50",
        "wmin": "1001",
        "wmax": "2000",
        "name": "Oltre 1000 g e fino a 2000 g"
      }
    },
    "7": {
      "1": {
        "price": "4.50",
        "wmin": "0",
        "wmax": "20",
        "name": "fino a 20 g"
      },
      "2": {
        "price": "5.80",
        "wmin": "21",
        "wmax": "50",
        "name": "Oltre 20 g e fino a 50 g "
      },
      "3": {
        "price": "6.20",
        "wmin": "51",
        "wmax": "100",
        "name": "Oltre 50 g e fino a 100 g"
      },
      "4": {
        "price": "6.70",
        "wmin": "101",
        "wmax": "250",
        "name": "Oltre 100 g e fino a 250 g"
      },
      "5": {
        "price": "7.50",
        "wmin": "251",
        "wmax": "350",
        "name": "Oltre 250 g e fino a 350 g"
      },
      "6": {
        "price": "9.20",
        "wmin": "351",
        "wmax": "1000",
        "name": "Oltre 350 g e fino a 1000 g"
      },
      "7": {
        "price": "12.30",
        "wmin": "1001",
        "wmax": "2000",
        "name": "Oltre 1000 g e fino a 2000 g"
      }
    },
    "8": {
      "1": {
        "price": "5.45",
        "wmin": "0",
        "wmax": "20",
        "name": "fino a 20 g"
      },
      "2": {
        "price": "6.75",
        "wmin": "21",
        "wmax": "50",
        "name": "Oltre 20 g e fino a 50 g "
      },
      "3": {
        "price": "7.15",
        "wmin": "51",
        "wmax": "100",
        "name": "Oltre 50 g e fino a 100 g"
      },
      "4": {
        "price": "7.65",
        "wmin": "101",
        "wmax": "250",
        "name": "Oltre 100 g e fino a 250 g"
      },
      "5": {
        "price": "8.45",
        "wmin": "251",
        "wmax": "350",
        "name": "Oltre 250 g e fino a 350 g"
      },
      "6": {
        "price": "10.15",
        "wmin": "351",
        "wmax": "1000",
        "name": "Oltre 350 g e fino a 1000 g"
      },
      "7": {
        "price": "13.25",
        "wmin": "1001",
        "wmax": "2000",
        "name": "Oltre 1000 g e fino a 2000 g"
      }
    }
  }

  ;
  //console.log(weightOptions);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it by separating the event handlers so that you don't keep updating weights as you use the first select. <strike>I changed the `$('.calculator-row')` selector to `$('.letterType, .letterNumber')` in order to avoid re-populating weights after changing the second select.</strike> One approach would be to use HTML5 templates and assign a unique id to the parent element. Then, use find to query children and update them accordingly.

```js
function UpdateTotal() {
  var total = 0;
  $('.letterNumber').each(function() {
    total += parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
  });

  $('#calcTotal').text(total);
}

function AddCalcRow() {
  var row = 'calc_row_' + $('.calculator-row').length;
  var rowId = '#' + row;
  var template = document.getElementById('template');
  template.content.querySelector('.calculator-row').id = row;

  var clone = document.importNode(template.content, true);
  document.getElementById('calculator').appendChild(clone);

  // Find and bind elements specific to the current row.
  $(rowId).find('.letterType').on('change', function(e) {
    // Update weight elements here.
    $(rowId).find('.letterWeight').append($('<option>' + Math.random() + '</option>'));
  });

  $(rowId).find('.letterNumber').on('input', function(e) {
    // Update subtotal.
    $(rowId).find('.letterSubtotal').text(e.target.value);
    UpdateTotal();
  });
}

document.getElementById('add').addEventListener('click', AddCalcRow);
AddCalcRow();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<template id="template">
  <div class="calculator-row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control letterType">
          <option value="1">Ordinaria piccolo</option>
          <option value="2">Ordinaria medio</option>
          <option value="3">Ordinaria extra</option>
          <option value="4">Raccomandata con avviso di ricevimento piccolo</option>
          <option value="5">Raccomandata con avviso di ricevimento medio</option>
          <option value="6">Raccomandata con avviso di ricevimento extra</option>
          <option value="7">Raccomandata semplice</option>
          <option value="8">Raccomandata con avviso di ricevimento</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control letterWeight"></select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="number" class="form-control letterNumber" placeholder="No." min="0" max="999">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <h4><span>&euro;
</span><span class="letterSubtotal">0.00</span></h4> 
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="calculator">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 center">
      <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button type="button" id="add" class="btn btn-default calcAddRow">Add
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default calcDelRow hidden">Remove
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-9">
      <h3><span>Totale: &euro;
</span><span id="calcTotal">0.00</span></h3> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Um... ok but that just broke the calculator. There are no results being displayed anymore.

Comment: Right, the idea was just to show how to have the select render the correct option, but I've updated the snippet to show how you can approach solving the issue. I just used dummy functions for now, but you can apply your original solution while keeping in mind that your handlers should address individual components to avoid having the select component not render the correct option. There are missing edge cases of course, but it's just meant to demonstrate how you can use JQuery and HTML5 for dynamically rendering rows

Comment: Hey, thank you, I didn't do it like that but your advice helped. I update my snippet, now it works.

Comment: Np! Glad I could help